# Gradle wrapper username and password not working from command line

Tags: java, gradle

I am using the following in my build.gradle file:

```
wrapper {
  gradleVersion = "5.4.1"
  distributionUrl = "https://mynexusserver.com/nexus/content/repositories/com/gradle/${gradleVersion}/gradle-${gradleVersion}-all.zip
}
```

This manages to download the gradle distribution if I have the following in my gradle.properties file:

```
systemProp.gradle.wrapperUser=xxx
systemProp.gradle.wrapperPassword=yyy
```

But it doesn't work (401) when I try adding them to the command line:

```
./gradlew clean build -Dgradle.wrapperUser=xxx -Dgradle.wrapperPassword=yyy
```

I've tried various combinations of -P and -D etc but it won't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, it was an ordering issue.  Whilst this wasn't working:

```
./gradlew clean build -Dgradle.wrapperUser=xxx -Dgradle.wrapperPassword=yyy
```

This does:

```
./gradlew -Dgradle.wrapperUser=xxx -Dgradle.wrapperPassword=yyy clean build
```

Comment: use P instead of D like this 
gradle -PartifactoryUsername=<username> -PartifactoryPassword=<password> clean build